# 10 second rule for food on ground

Tags: eating

Throughout the secular world I've heard the expression "10 second rule" whenever a piece of food has fallen to the ground (and someone still wants to eat it).

The 10 second rule permits the food to be eaten.

Is there any such idea in Judaism? This question is not about the kashrus of the food but rather about whether it can be eaten for reasons of cleanliness after it has fallen to the ground?

Comment: does this presume that under halacha, food which fell on the floor would normally be assur so it needs a heter?

Comment: I think "the rule" is regional. In New York, it is 30 seconds. I have heard some claim as long as thirty minutes in other parts of the country. Of course, "the rule" applies only to men no matter how sexist that may seem. (Stereotypically, Women will not eat any food falling onto the floor.) But seriously folks........I am rather certain that any concept of cleanliness is more spiritual than physical. Food falling on the floor would not render it non-kosher unless it touches something unkosher. If so, I am rather certain there is no minimum time of contact that would render it as such.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think so. This question isn't clear about whether the asker is concerned about _hilchos taaruvos_ or about _mius_, but the [tag:kashrut-kosher] tag that he or she applied to it makes it seem like the former, which would make it a duplicate. I'm closing it; asker, if you meant something different from the linked-to question, please [edit] this one to clarify your intent.